Problem with adding image avatar on three.js globe
I am preparing a 3d globe with three.js and I already achieve the rotating globe with below code.
HTML
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

JS
let camera;
let renderer;


function main()
{
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');


    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(65, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 2;
    scene.add(camera);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas, antialias: true,});
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

    renderer.autoClear = false;
    renderer.setClearColor(0x00000, 0.0);


    // create earthgeometry

    const earthgeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.6,32,32);

    const eatrhmaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        roughness : 1,
        metalness:0,
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture/earthmap1k.jpg'),
        bumpMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture/earthbump.jpg'),
        bumpScale: 0.3,
    });

    const earthmesh = new THREE.Mesh(earthgeometry,eatrhmaterial);

    scene.add(earthmesh);

    // set ambientlight

    const ambientlight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.1);
    scene.add(ambientlight);

    // set point light

    const pointerlight =  new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff,0.9);

    // set light position

    pointerlight.position.set(5,3,5);
    scene.add(pointerlight);

    const animate = () =>{
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        earthmesh.rotation.y += 0.0015;
        render();
    }

    const render = () => {
        renderer.render(scene,camera);
    }

    animate();
}

window.onload = main;

Now I want to add some image avatar which will also attached with globe and rotate with globe. Reference: https://zinannadeem.sirv.com/Images/globe.gif (What I am looking for)
I am seeking some help how can i add some image avatar on the three.js globe which will rotate with globe itself ?
If you want to test with my globe images here you can grab (https://zinannadeem.sirv.com/Images/earthmap1k.jpg https://zinannadeem.sirv.com/Images/earthbump.jpg)

Just create plane geometry with material and assign avatar image as map parameter on material (as you did with globe). Then attach plane (globe.attach(avatarMesh)) to globe and position it on right position. To make avatar image look on camera all the time, use lookAt function.
//create plane geometry with width 1 and height 1, maybe you will need to adjust it 
const avatarGeometry: PlaneGeometry = new PlaneGeometry(1, 1, 1, 1);
// use png texture to make transparent object
const avatarTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture/avatar1.png'),
const avatarMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  map: texture,
  transparent: true,
});
const avatar = new Mesh(avatarGeometry, avatarMaterial);
// attach avatar to globe, it will rotate when globe rotate
earthmesh.attach(avatar)
avatar.position.set(2,2,2) //now you must position avatar outside of globe, so test it to get right position 

And update your animate function to
const animate = () =>{
     requestAnimationFrame(animate);
     earthmesh.rotation.y += 0.0015;
     avatar.lookAt(camera.position) //to make avatars look on camera
     render();
}

I don't test it, but it should work.
For finding best positions for your avatar I recomend install threejs devtools for chrome (you must compile them first) from this repo - https://github.com/oslabs-beta/BACE. It can very help with debugging.
Another solution is use css3D renderer to render avatar as html element. But it's little more complicated. Check three js examples - https://threejs.org/examples/?q=css3d#css3d_periodictable. But it get more complicated if you want combined it with 3d object.

Can i get little bit more explanation or sample full code, if possible ?

yes, give me 30 minutes I will update my post with code

Sure I am waiting ..

It's edited. I hope it will help.

Sorry, there showing some console error. I humbly request you to just check the code help me to get the proper solution with working code. Thanks

I edit code to use THREE imports. But without codepen is hard to help you more. Try go trough my code step by step. First you need create 3d plane and put image texture to it. This is what first part of code is doing. You should have plane with avatar image on it (I use some tmp path, you must add right image path).
And after creation just add it under earth geometry to make it rotate with globe.
Second part it to make avatar plane looking alltime to camera.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
